# Hylafax modems stuck in "Sending job" state

Tags: at-command, fax

I have 12 modems connected to my HylaFax server, it appears that sometimes i get some of my modems stuck in "Sending job" state till i disconnect the line from the modem to get the job killed.

The modem can stay in this state forever without any notice, here's what i get in the server traces for the job being stuck:

```
Jan 26 10:33:53.57: [29579]: SESSION BEGIN 000028267 79137356
Jan 26 10:33:53.57: [29579]: HylaFAX (tm) Version 6.0.6
Jan 26 10:33:53.57: [29579]: SEND FAX: JOB 5166 DEST 79137356 COMMID 000028267 DEVICE '/dev/ttyT38-23' FROM 'tuxfax <tuxfax@tuxfax.tux>' USER apache
Jan 26 10:33:53.57: [29579]: STATE CHANGE: RUNNING -> SENDING
Jan 26 10:33:53.57: [29579]: <-- [12:AT+FCLASS=1\r]
Jan 26 10:33:53.57: [29579]: --> [2:OK]
Jan 26 10:33:53.57: [29579]: DIAL 79137356
Jan 26 10:33:53.57: [29579]: <-- [10:ATDT79137356\r]
Jan 26 10:34:09.51: [29579]: --> [7:CONNECT]
Jan 26 10:34:17.55: [29579]: --> HDLC<40:FF C0 04 FF FF FF FF 73 1D 01 01 88 A1 B0 BB 00 00 BB BB 00 00 BB BB 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B7 44 0D 00 00 09 00 E1 4F>
Jan 26 10:34:17.55: [29579]: --> [2:OK]
Jan 26 10:34:17.55: [29579]: REMOTE NSF "FF FF FF FF CE B8 80 80 11 85 0D DD 00 00 DD DD 00 00 DD DD 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ED 22 B0 00 00 90 00"
Jan 26 10:34:17.55: [29579]: NSF remote fax equipment: unknown 
Jan 26 10:34:17.55: [29579]: <-- [9:AT+FRH=3\r]
Jan 26 10:34:17.56: [29579]: --> [7:CONNECT]
Jan 26 10:34:18.27: [29579]: --> HDLC<25:FF C0 02 CC 9C 4C AC 1C 4C 4C EC 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 04 8B C9>
Jan 26 10:34:18.27: [29579]: --> [2:OK]
Jan 26 10:34:18.27: [29579]: REMOTE CSI "77225292"
Jan 26 10:34:18.27: [29579]: <-- [9:AT+FRH=3\r]
Jan 26 10:34:18.28: [29579]: --> [7:CONNECT]
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: --> HDLC<11:FF C8 01 00 73 1D 01 01 88 03 AE>
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: --> [2:OK]
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: REMOTE best rate 9600 bit/s
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: REMOTE max A4 page width (215 mm)
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: REMOTE max unlimited page length
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: REMOTE best vres 15.4 line/mm
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: REMOTE format support: MH, MR
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: REMOTE best 20 ms, 10 ms/scanline
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: USE 9600 bit/s
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: SEND file "docq/doc5166.pdf;f0"
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: USE A4 page width (215 mm)
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: USE unlimited page length
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: USE 3.85 line/mm
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: USE 2-D MR
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: USE 20 ms/scanline
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: SEND training at v.29 9600 bit/s
Jan 26 10:34:18.61: [29579]: <-- [9:AT+FRS=7\r]
Jan 26 10:34:18.69: [29579]: --> [2:OK]
Jan 26 10:34:18.69: [29579]: <-- [9:AT+FTH=3\r]
Jan 26 10:34:18.69: [29579]: --> [7:CONNECT]
Jan 26 10:34:18.69: [29579]: <-- HDLC<23:FF C0 C2 1C 1C 1C 0C 2C CC 8C EC F4 0C AC EC 4C CC 04 0A F2 C2 22 04>
Jan 26 10:34:18.69: [29579]: <-- data [23]
Jan 26 10:34:18.69: [29579]: <-- data [2]
Jan 26 10:34:20.23: [29579]: --> [7:CONNECT]
Jan 26 10:34:20.23: [29579]: <-- HDLC<6:FF C8 C1 00 61 10>
Jan 26 10:34:20.23: [29579]: <-- data [6]
Jan 26 10:34:20.23: [29579]: <-- data [2]
Jan 26 10:34:20.53: [29579]: --> [2:OK]
Jan 26 10:34:20.53: [29579]: <-- [9:AT+FTS=7\r]
Jan 26 10:34:20.66: [29579]: --> [2:OK]
Jan 26 10:34:20.66: [29579]: <-- [10:AT+FTM=96\r]
Jan 26 10:34:20.66: [29579]: --> [7:CONNECT]
Jan 26 10:34:20.66: [29579]: <-- data [1024]
Jan 26 10:34:20.66: [29579]: <-- data [776]
Jan 26 10:34:20.66: [29579]: <-- data [2]
Jan 26 10:34:22.52: [29579]: --> [2:OK]
Jan 26 10:34:22.52: [29579]: <-- [9:AT+FRH=3\r]
Jan 26 10:34:23.47: [29579]: --> [7:CONNECT]
Jan 26 10:34:24.51: [29579]: --> HDLC<5:FF C8 21 57 BE>
Jan 26 10:34:24.51: [29579]: --> [2:OK]
Jan 26 10:34:24.51: [29579]: TRAINING succeeded
Jan 26 10:34:24.51: [29579]: <-- [9:AT+FRS=7\r]
Jan 26 10:34:24.59: [29579]: --> [2:OK]
Jan 26 10:34:24.59: [29579]: <-- [10:AT+FTM=96\r]
Jan 26 10:34:24.59: [29579]: --> [7:CONNECT]
Jan 26 10:34:24.59: [29579]: SEND begin page
Jan 26 10:34:24.59: [29579]: Reading MMR-compressed image file
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1029]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1024]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1024]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1024]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1024]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1026]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1043]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1039]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1042]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1034]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1034]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1036]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1032]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1028]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1035]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1033]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1033]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1030]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1027]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1026]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1025]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1035]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1028]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1024]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1030]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [264]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: SENT 25864 bytes of data
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1031]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1038]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [1039]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [868]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: SENT 3931 bytes of data
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: SEND 2D RTC
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [30]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: <-- data [2]
Jan 26 10:34:24.60: [29579]: SEND end page
Jan 26 10:34:49.80: [29579]: --> [2:OK]
Jan 26 10:34:49.80: [29579]: <-- [9:AT+FTS=9\r]
Jan 26 10:34:49.96: [29579]: --> [2:OK]
Jan 26 10:34:49.96: [29579]: SEND send EOP (no more pages or documents)
Jan 26 10:34:49.96: [29579]: <-- [9:AT+FTH=3\r]
Jan 26 10:34:49.96: [29579]: --> [7:CONNECT]
Jan 26 10:34:49.96: [29579]: <-- HDLC<3:FF C8 F4>
Jan 26 10:34:49.96: [29579]: <-- data [3]
Jan 26 10:34:49.96: [29579]: <-- data [2]
Jan 26 10:34:51.00: [29579]: --> [2:OK]
Jan 26 10:34:51.00: [29579]: <-- [9:AT+FRH=3\r]
Jan 26 10:34:51.87: [29579]: --> [7:CONNECT]
Jan 26 10:34:52.91: [29579]: --> HDLC<5:FF C8 5F C8 E7>
Jan 26 10:34:52.91: [29579]: --> [2:OK]
Jan 26 10:34:52.91: [29579]: SEND recv DCN (disconnect)
Jan 26 10:34:52.91: [29579]: Remote fax disconnected prematurely
Jan 26 10:34:52.91: [29579]: <-- [9:AT+FRS=7\r]
Jan 26 10:34:52.98: [29579]: --> [2:OK]
Jan 26 10:34:52.98: [29579]: <-- [9:AT+FTH=3\r]
Jan 26 10:34:52.99: [29579]: --> [7:CONNECT]
Jan 26 10:34:52.99: [29579]: <-- HDLC<3:FF C8 DF>
Jan 26 10:34:52.99: [29579]: <-- data [3]
Jan 26 10:34:52.99: [29579]: <-- data [2]
```

As i understand, the modem is waiting (forever) for the remote fax to respond.

Server configuration is: HylaFax 6.0.6 / CentOS 6.3

The questions are:

1. Is there any config parameter to avoid this kind of freezing in Hylafax ?
2. As a quick workaround, i can write a script to monitor sending jobs and kill a job that is lasting in a "Sending job", but i dont find anyway to kill a running job (not a queued job)

Comment: hi, what is the question???

Comment: i've just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I had only some light exposure to fax when working with mobile phone development, but I learned that fax was a "test, test, test" issue that was much effort in getting to work (when running over GSM the fax code even had to start sending responses in some cases for things it expected to receive because of some impossible timing issue). And even if you implemented everything according to the specification, things were not guaranteed to work. There is a reason that most (all?) mobile network and phones have dropped support for fax today.

> As i understand, the modem is waiting (forever) for the remote fax to respond.

This might be the case, and as I understand it there it could be that there is no blame to put on neither the remote fax machine nor on hylafax. Implementing some monitoring service seems to be the only sensible and reliable way of handling this.